# Magento 2 ajax is not working

Tags: ajax, magento2.2.6

I am trying to save form details using AJAX. Below is my Code.

**etc/adminhtml/routes.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="adminpath" frontName="adminpath">
            <module name="My_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**view/adminhtml/templates/page.phtml**

```
<form class="authorize-form">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">name:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" name = "name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Email:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10"> 
                  <input type="text" name = "email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                </div>
            </div>

            <button type="button" id="submit" onclick="formsave()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>    

        </form>
<script>

 function formsave()
    {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $block->getUrl('adminpath/ajaxcontroller'); ?>',
            showLoader: true,
            data: {name:name,email:email},
            type: "POST",
            success: function(result){
                alert("I am inside the success");
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**controller/adminhtml/Ajaxcontroller**

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Controller\Adminhtml;

class Ajaxcontroller extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        if($this->getRequest()->isAjax()){
            echo "Testing";
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me what's wrong here. It's not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You controller should be at path:

```
My\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Ajaxcontroller\Index.php
```

You are using the action url as `<?php echo $block->getUrl('adminpath/ajaxcontroller'); ?>`
 which will call adminpath route's, ajaxcontroller's index action.

> `<?php echo $block->getUrl('adminpath/ajaxcontroller'); ?>`

and

> `<?php echo $block->getUrl('adminpath/ajaxcontroller/index'); ?>`

both are same in short.

Add Index.php at path My\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Ajaxcontroller with below code:

```
namespace My\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Ajaxcontroller;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        if($this->getRequest()->isAjax()){
            echo "Testing";
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @himmatpaliwal . It is working now

Comment: Great! Happy to help :)

Comment: url: '<?php echo $block->getUrl('adminpath/ajaxcontroller', ['form_key' => $block->getFormKey()]); ?>'    // This is working

 url: '<?php echo $block->getUrl('adminpath/ajaxcontroller') ?>'  // This is not working.

please explain why this thing happnes

Comment: No, it would also not work. Can you check by renaming My\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Ajaxcontroller\Index.php to any other name?